# C# Change revisions made to word document?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, office-interop

I am working on a project where I am making changes to an existing word document using the Word Interop tools. However when I am done with these changes and save the data, I look at the properties and it shows that I made the changes at the current time. Is there a way where let's say the document was last accessed a week ago, after I make the changes and save it, it still shows the document was last opened a week ago?

Comment: LastAccessed is different than LastModified. Please check LastModified data time instead LastAccessed.

Comment: I would like to keep the last accessed and last modified both the same as it previously was before the document was opened and made changes to.

Comment: where you are trying to keep that both information?

Comment: Pretty sure the ONLY way you're going to be able to do this is to change the system date/time, do your work, save it and then set the system date/time back. Of course, this could lead to a whole mess of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer. I have posted a sample code below if anyone else is interested! It preserves the last modified and last accessed property of the word document.

```
//filePath is a string with the location of your word document
DateTime preserveAccess = File.GetLastAccessTime(filePath);
DateTime preserveModify = File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath);

//Some code to open the document, make changes, and then save it back
//Now the last accessed and modified data will be different than before

//You can set the last accessed and modified to the original that you 
//retrieved before making any changes to the document

File.SetLastAccessTime(filePath, preserveAccess);
File.SetLastWriteTime(filePath, preserveModify);
```